# AtomSite.net Source - “Publish” does not appear under “Build” menu in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am trying to install AtomSite.net on my server. I am working off of my server (Win2k3, all patches & updates) and have Visual Studio 2008 installed. I have AtomSite in a separate directory well away from the IIS root directories (which are on a different drive to protect the OS from transverse directory attacks).

When I open the AtomSite project, the AtomSite notes state that I should be able to right-click on WebCore, and select Publish from the drop-down menu. This does not happen. In fact, I cannot find Publish anywhere.

WTF??

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Web Developer Express by any chance? Publish is not available under VWD Express, only VS Pro and above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the full version of Visual Studio 2008.